# postgres encoding error in sidekiq app

Tags: ruby, postgresql, encoding, sequel

I am working on an application where a ruby sidekiq process calls a 3rd party and parses the data into a database.

I am using sequel ad my orm.

I am getting some weird characters back in the results, for example:

> "Tweets en Ingl\xE9s y en Espa\xF1ol"

When this gets attempted to save to postgres, the following error happens:

> Sequel::DatabaseError: PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR:  invalid
>   byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe9 0x73 0x20

The weird thing is that the string thinks it is UTF-8, if I check the encoding name, it says:

```
name.encoding.name #UTF-8
```

What can I do to ensure that the data is in the correct format for postgres?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because the string claims to be UTF-8 doesn't mean that it is UTF-8. `\xe9` is `é` in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) (AKA Latin-1) but it is invalid in UTF-8; similarly, `\xf1` is `ñ` in ISO-8859-1 but invalid in UTF-8. That suggests that the string is actually encoded in ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8. You can fix it with a combination of [`force_encoding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) to correct Ruby's confusion about the current encoding and [`encode`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-encode) to re-encode it as UTF-8:

```
> "Tweets en Ingl\xE9s y en Espa\xF1ol".force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
=> "Tweets en Inglés y en Español"
```

So before sending that string to the database you want to:

```
name = name.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to reliably detect a string's real encoding. The various encodings overlap and there's no way to tell if `è` (`\xe8` in ISO-8859-1) or `č` (`\xe8` in ISO-8859-2) is the right character without manual sanity checking.